# Symfony querybuilder orderby failed

Tags: symfony, query-builder

in a querybuilder i do an orderby, but if i orderby a 'leftjoin' my orderby doesn't work and i don't understand why.

My querybuilder :

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->leftJoin('r.clientCategorisation', 'cc')
        ->leftJoin('cc.categorisation', 'c')
        ->addOrderBy('c.id','ASC')
    $a_result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    return $a_result;
```

If i orderby my 'r', its ok, but if i try to order 'c' that does't work ...
I can order my 'c' asc if in my view html.twig i add  :

```
{{  clientCategorisation.categorisation.id}}
```

I don't understand why ??? And this method work only for 'asc', 'desc' failed.

Edit : I have a datatable and in my table my order is on an object :

```
A_resultats = $this->_O_resultatsR->getByRapportOrderByCat($idRapport, $A_onglet);
```

getByRapportOrderByCat is my querybuilder.

Then in a foreach :

```
foreach ( $A_resultats as $I_key => $O_resultat ) {
```

i construct my columns, and in this column 'analyse':

```
$A_valuesForTableau[$I_key]['analyse'] = $this->render('mypath', array(
                    'O_resultat'        => $O_resultat,
                    'A_clientCats'        => $A_clientCats,
            ))->getContent();
```

i give again my object $O_resultat to the template (if a comment this object in analyse my order is nice) and i think in the template my order from querybuilder is replace by order by asc (basic order by).

Sorry for my bad english.

edit2 : 
Entity resutat : 
    class Resultat
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ClientCategorisation")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_categorisation", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=true)
     */
    private $clientCategorisation;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set clientCategorisation
     *
     * @param ClientCategorisation $clientCategorisation
     * @return Resultat
     */
    public function setClientCategorisation(ClientCategorisation $clientCategorisation = null)
    {
        $this->clientCategorisation = $clientCategorisation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get clientCategorisation
     *
     * @return ClientCategorisation 
     */
    public function getClientCategorisation()
    {
        return $this->clientCategorisation;
    }

}
```

Entity clientcategorisation :

```
class ClientCategorisation 
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categorisation")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categorisation", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $categorisation;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set categorisation
     *
     * @param string $categorisation
     * @return ClientCategorisation
     */
    public function setCategorisation($categorisation)
    {
        $this->categorisation = $categorisation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get categorisation
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCategorisation()
    {
        return $this->categorisation;
    }

}
```

categorisation entity :

```
class Categorisation
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ordre", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $ordre;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     * @return Categorisation
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }


    /**
     * Set ordre
     *
     * @param integer $ordre
     * @return Categorisation
     */
    public function setOrdre($ordre)
    {
        $this->ordre = $ordre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ordre
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getOrdre()
    {
        return $this->ordre;
    }
}
```

edit2 : I have found a solution, when i use 'O_resultat' my order fail, so in my template i get 'A_resultats' and that work like this :

```
{% for O_resultats in A_resultats %}
    {% if O_resultats.id == O_resultat.id %}
```

and i replace in my vieuw O_resultat  by O_resultats

Comment: *my orderby doesn't work* Please provide an error message.

Comment: i don't have error message, but if i have : 1 to 9, in asc i have 1,2,3...9.
And here i have 2,3,5,8,1 ...

Comment: can you write the fields that you want to use in your twig

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the field as select argument and mark as [hidden](https://michelsalib.com/2012/03/04/doctrine2-ninja-with-the-hidden-keyword/) in order to don't modify the hydration flow (object instead of array) as follow:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->addSelect('c.id as HIDDEN mysort')
        ->leftJoin('r.clientCategorisation', 'cc')
        ->leftJoin('cc.categorisation', 'c')
        ->addOrderBy('mysort','ASC');
    $a_result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $a_result;
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thnaks but i have the same problem :/ that doesn't work too, my c.id is not order

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have `order-by` tag or `orderBy` annotation in `categorisation` relation of `clientCategorisation` mapping. If you have that annotation, your order is explicitly merged by your order created in `query builder`.

Example:

```
<?php

/** @Entity **/
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
     * @OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})
     **/
    private $groups;
}
```

If you create query like this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('user')
    ->leftJoin('user.groups', 'group')
    ->orderBy('group.name', 'DESC')
;
```

The final query executed by doctrine will be:

```
SELECT user FROM User LEFT JOIN user.groups group ORDER BY group.id ASC, group.name DESC;
```

So that the result will be ordered by `group.id` ASC (which is defined in your mapping), then ordered by `group.name` DESC (which is defined in your query builder).

If you want to be able to sort by `group.name DESC` (in example), you have to remove `@OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})` in annotation.

See [Ordering To-Many Associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have any orderby :/
I have edit my first post for more informations

Comment: Could you update your question including the 3 models and mappings you mentioned in query?